# Pyqt5 rendering is different on each platform, what can I do to render them the same?

Tags: python, pyqt, rendering, platform

I have some issues with pyqt5 development as I'm trying making a software that should be used on every platforms (Windows, MacOS and Linux).
When I execute the same script on each platform, I get different rendering results.
It seems to be mostly due to the font and size of the text which are different on each platform. For instance, the pushbutton on the bottom cannot contain the text for MacOS and Linux platforms. The size of some items are also different (see the pushbutton on the bottom)
I'm wondering if their is an easy solution to render the window mostly identical on each platform?

Here are the results on each platform:
[image]

obtained with this script:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys 

class GUI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GUI, self).__init__()
        self.parent = parent
        self.setFixedWidth(400)
        self.setFixedHeight(300)

        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.mainHBOX_param_scene = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setmarginandspacing(self.mainHBOX_param_scene)

        self.Ident_apply = QPushButton('Blablabla')

        self.GB1 = QGroupBox("Identification")
        self.GB1_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.Param_0_l = QLabel('Delay')
        self.Param_0_e = QLineEdit('1')
        self.GB1_layout.addWidget(self.Param_0_l)
        self.GB1_layout.addWidget(self.Param_0_e)
        self.GB1.setLayout(self.GB1_layout)


        self.GB2 = QGroupBox("Identification")
        self.GB2_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        grid = QGridLayout()
        self.GB2_layout.addLayout(grid)

        self.RB_Ident = QButtonGroup()
        self.RB_DL  =QRadioButton('DoubleLayer')
        self.RB_CPE= QRadioButton('CPE')
        self.RB_Ident.addButton(self.RB_DL)
        self.RB_Ident.addButton(self.RB_CPE)
        self.RB_DL.setChecked(True)
        self.Fixed_delay  = QCheckBox('Fixed delay?')
        self.Fixed_delay.setChecked(False)

        self.Param_0_l = QLabel('Delay')
        self.Param_0_e = QLineEdit('1')
        self.Param_1_l = QLabel('I(Rs+2*Rcable)')
        self.Param_1_e = QLineEdit('1')
        self.Param_2_l = QLabel('2*I*Zf')
        self.Param_2_e = QLineEdit('1')
        self.Param_3_l = QLabel('Cdl*Zf')
        self.Param_3_e = QLineEdit('1')


        self.Ident_apply = QPushButton('Apply')
        self.Ident_updatepguess = QPushButton('Update Pguess')

        self.Optim_Ident = QButtonGroup()
        self.Optim_curve_fit  =QRadioButton('Curve fit')
        self.Optim_minimize= QRadioButton('minimize')
        self.Optim_basin_hopping= QRadioButton('basin hopping')
        self.Optim_Ident.addButton(self.Optim_curve_fit)
        self.Optim_Ident.addButton(self.Optim_minimize)
        self.Optim_Ident.addButton(self.Optim_basin_hopping)
        self.Optim_curve_fit.setChecked(True)

        grid.addWidget(self.RB_DL, 0, 0 )
        grid.addWidget(self.RB_CPE, 0, 1 )
        grid.addWidget(self.Fixed_delay, 0, 3 )
        grid.addWidget(self.Param_0_l, 1, 0 )
        grid.addWidget(self.Param_1_l, 1, 1 )
        grid.addWidget(self.Param_2_l, 1, 2 )
        grid.addWidget(self.Param_3_l, 1, 3 )
        grid.addWidget(self.Param_0_e, 2, 0 )
        grid.addWidget(self.Param_1_e, 2, 1 )
        grid.addWidget(self.Param_2_e, 2, 2 )
        grid.addWidget(self.Param_3_e, 2, 3 )
        grid.addWidget(self.Optim_curve_fit, 3, 0 )
        grid.addWidget(self.Optim_minimize, 3, 1 )
        grid.addWidget(self.Optim_basin_hopping, 3, 2 )
        grid.addWidget(self.Ident_updatepguess, 4, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.Ident_apply, 4, 3, )
        self.GB2.setLayout(self.GB2_layout)

        self.mainHBOX_param_scene.addWidget(self.Ident_apply)
        self.mainHBOX_param_scene.addWidget(self.GB1)
        self.mainHBOX_param_scene.addWidget(self.GB2)
        self.centralWidget.setLayout(self.mainHBOX_param_scene)

    def setmarginandspacing(self,layout):
        layout.setContentsMargins(5,5,5,5)
        layout.setSpacing(5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = GUI(app)
    ex.show()
    ex.setWindowTitle('Windows')
    sys.exit(app.exec_( ))
```

Comment: It's usually a mistake to enforce a fixed width/height - you should allow the dialog to resize to whatever is required to accommodate all the widgets.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, I just fix the window size here. How it can be a mistake?

Comment: It is a mistake, because the user must be allowed to use whatever fonts or widget style they like (e.g. a visually-impaired person will need to use large fonts). If you fix the size, there is no guarantee that everything will fit in the available space on all systems.

Comment: For the contents in the QGridLayout you won't get around giving them more horizontal space, i.e. increase the window width, fixed or not (although I'd also make it flexible only for user experience reasons). For some of your widgets like the "update" button or the radio buttons you could also just put them outside of the grid into their own QHorizontalLayout over the whole width, with a spacer beside them and a sizePolicy set to minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to render the same on every platform, I suggest you set the styling in the start. To give yourself a code with a fusion style, your code could look like this:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
app = QApplication([])
app.setStyle('Fusion')
#Your code ...
```

The different styles you can choose are listed down below:

```
'Windows', 'GTK+', 'Fusion'
```

The `Windows` option will make your code look like it is running on windows, `GTK+` on GTK+ platform, a `Fusion` its own unique one.

The code for a Windows look (using your code) will look like this:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys 

class GUI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GUI, self).__init__()
        self.parent = parent
        self.setFixedWidth(400)
        self.setFixedHeight(300)

        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.mainHBOX_param_scene = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setmarginandspacing(self.mainHBOX_param_scene)

        self.Ident_apply = QPushButton('Blablabla')

        self.GB1 = QGroupBox("Identification")
        self.GB1_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.Param_0_l = QLabel('Delay')
        self.Param_0_e = QLineEdit('1')
        self.GB1_layout.addWidget(self.Param_0_l)
        self.GB1_layout.addWidget(self.Param_0_e)
        self.GB1.setLayout(self.GB1_layout)


        self.GB2 = QGroupBox("Identification")
        self.GB2_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        grid = QGridLayout()
        self.GB2_layout.addLayout(grid)

        self.RB_Ident = QButtonGroup()
        self.RB_DL  =QRadioButton('DoubleLayer')
        self.RB_CPE= QRadioButton('CPE')
        self.RB_Ident.addButton(self.RB_DL)
        self.RB_Ident.addButton(self.RB_CPE)
        self.RB_DL.setChecked(True)
        self.Fixed_delay  = QCheckBox('Fixed delay?')
        self.Fixed_delay.setChecked(False)

        self.Param_0_l = QLabel('Delay')
        self.Param_0_e = QLineEdit('1')
        self.Param_1_l = QLabel('I(Rs+2*Rcable)')
        self.Param_1_e = QLineEdit('1')
        self.Param_2_l = QLabel('2*I*Zf')
        self.Param_2_e = QLineEdit('1')
        self.Param_3_l = QLabel('Cdl*Zf')
        self.Param_3_e = QLineEdit('1')


        self.Ident_apply = QPushButton('Apply')
        self.Ident_updatepguess = QPushButton('Update Pguess')

        self.Optim_Ident = QButtonGroup()
        self.Optim_curve_fit  =QRadioButton('Curve fit')
        self.Optim_minimize= QRadioButton('minimize')
        self.Optim_basin_hopping= QRadioButton('basin hopping')
        self.Optim_Ident.addButton(self.Optim_curve_fit)
        self.Optim_Ident.addButton(self.Optim_minimize)
        self.Optim_Ident.addButton(self.Optim_basin_hopping)
        self.Optim_curve_fit.setChecked(True)

        grid.addWidget(self.RB_DL, 0, 0 )
        grid.addWidget(self.RB_CPE, 0, 1 )
        grid.addWidget(self.Fixed_delay, 0, 3 )
        grid.addWidget(self.Param_0_l, 1, 0 )
        grid.addWidget(self.Param_1_l, 1, 1 )
        grid.addWidget(self.Param_2_l, 1, 2 )
        grid.addWidget(self.Param_3_l, 1, 3 )
        grid.addWidget(self.Param_0_e, 2, 0 )
        grid.addWidget(self.Param_1_e, 2, 1 )
        grid.addWidget(self.Param_2_e, 2, 2 )
        grid.addWidget(self.Param_3_e, 2, 3 )
        grid.addWidget(self.Optim_curve_fit, 3, 0 )
        grid.addWidget(self.Optim_minimize, 3, 1 )
        grid.addWidget(self.Optim_basin_hopping, 3, 2 )
        grid.addWidget(self.Ident_updatepguess, 4, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.Ident_apply, 4, 3, )
        self.GB2.setLayout(self.GB2_layout)

        self.mainHBOX_param_scene.addWidget(self.Ident_apply)
        self.mainHBOX_param_scene.addWidget(self.GB1)
        self.mainHBOX_param_scene.addWidget(self.GB2)
        self.centralWidget.setLayout(self.mainHBOX_param_scene)

    def setmarginandspacing(self,layout):
        layout.setContentsMargins(5,5,5,5)
        layout.setSpacing(5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Windows')
    ex = GUI(app)
    ex.show()
    ex.setWindowTitle('Windows style')
    sys.exit(app.exec_( ))
```

This should give an output like this:

[image: Output]

Another way to do this is to get a `.qss` stylesheet, or make your own. [Here](http://dgovil.com/blog/2017/02/24/qt_stylesheets/) is a short tutorial on making `.qss` stylesheets.

Comment: Note that the Wiindows style is not available on Linux and OS-X. The Fusion style is available on all three major platforms. See https://blog.qt.io/blog/2012/10/30/cleaning-up-styles-in-qt5-and-adding-fusion/

Comment: @titusjan it seems like windows style is available on OS-X. I tried it out (pic above).

Comment: Nice, it works on OS_X indeed, I don't know yet about Linux.